# Case-insensitive hash-keys in Regexp::Grammars

Tags: regex, perl, regexp-grammars

In the perl module Regexp::Grammars, consider the following token:

```
<token: command>       <%commands>
```

This token is part of a complex grammar, parsing a wide variety of different sentences.

This token matches any word in the hash %commands, which I have defined as follows (of course, outside any function):

```
our %commands = (
    'Basic_import'  => 1,
    'Wait'          => 1,
    'Reload'        => 1,
    'Log'           => 1,
);
```

This works, for matching keywords like "Basic_import", "Wait", etc. However, I also want it to match on words like "basic_import", "wait", etc.

How do I make this hash case insensitive without having to copy and paste every keyword multiple times? Because this is part of a complex grammar, I want to use Regexp::Grammars, and I'd prefer not to have to revert to a grep for this particular exception.

Comment: Not a dup of that. This is a Regexp::Grammars question

Comment: Unfortunately, Tieing the hash doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @psgels, Does `(?i: <%commands> )` work? If not, you may need to build the pattern yourself.

Comment: @ikegami: unfortunately, it does not. What do you mean by building the pattern myself?

Comment: Either dynamically or statically build a regex pattern that matches the keys of the hash insensitively, and using that pattern in the grammar instead of `<%commands>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Hash::Case::Preserve](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::Case::Preserve) to make hash lookups case insensitive:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Dump;
use Hash::Case::Preserve;
use Regexp::Grammars;

tie my %commands, 'Hash::Case::Preserve';

%commands = (
    'Basic_import'  => 1,
    'Wait'          => 1,
    'Reload'        => 1,
    'Log'           => 1,
);

my $grammar = qr{

    <command>

    <token: command>    <%commands>

};  

dd \%/ if 'basic_import' =~ $grammar;
```

Output:

```
{ "" => "basic_import", "command" => "basic_import" }
```

Note that you have to `tie` the hash *before* inserting any values into it.

Comment: Yes, this one works. I must have mistyped something when I tried it the first time. Thanks!

Comment: Tip: `<token: command> \b <%commands> \b` would be better, as it addresses the `printfoo();` vs `print foo();` problem I mentioned in my answer. (You'll need to adjust if the keys of `%commands` can start or end with something other than a `\w` char).

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation, it sounds like `<%commands>` would match `Wait` of `Waiting`, so even a case-insensitive version of `<%commands>` would be less than ideal.

You normally want to match a generic identifier, and independently check if the identifier is a valid command. This is what prevents `printfoo();` from being equivalent to `print foo();` in Perl.

May I suggest the following:

```
use feature qw( fc );

our %commands = map { fc($_) => 1 } qw(
   Basic_import
   Wait
   Reload
   Log
); 

<rule: command> (<ident>) <require: (?{ $commands{fc($CAPTURE)} })>

<token: ident> \w+
```

You can probably get away with using `lc` instead of `fc` if you want backwards compatibility with version of Perl older than 5.16.

Comment: "From the documentation, it sounds like..." Confirmed. I've never used Regexp::Grammars but it seems to have a weird idea of what a token is. You can also get around this by adding anchors to the pattern: `my $grammar = qr{ \A <command> \z <token: command> <%commands> };`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, You don't want to have to enforce the boundary everywhere `<command>` is used. The check should be inside the token. Instead, use `<token: command> \b <%commands> \b` (though that assumes that all the keys of `%commands` start and end with a `\w` char.)

Answer (score 0):

```
%commands = map { lc($_) => 1, $_ => 1 } qw(
    Basic_import
    Wait
    Reload
    Log
);
```